# User defined immutables in python w/o subclassing

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

I know you're apparently not actually *supposed* to be able to define your own immutable object classes in Python (why the heck not?), but I have a very good reason to want to do so.

This object *needs* to have arbitrary attributes (that is, its attributes are specified at instantiation time and the only requirement is that their values are hashable) and yet *needs* to be immutable, as my architecture requires that it be used as a dictionary key (to look up callback functions, if anyone cares).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class InputEvent:
    """Instances of this class represent a discrete input event, such as a keyboard button being depressed or released,
    the mouse moving, or the OS asking us to terminate. These are immutable. The .eventtype attr is a string with a
    machine name identifying what caused the event; other parameters may be present dependent on the event type.

    Additional parameters may be passed in to the constructor as keyword arguments. All parameters must be hashable."""


    def __new__(cls,eventtype,**kwargs):
        newevent=super().__new__(cls)
        newevent.eventtype=eventtype
        for attr,value in kwargs.items():
            try:
                hash(value)
            except TypeError:
                raise TypeError("Tried to add a {0} instance, which is unhashable, as a parameter of an InputEvent".format(value.__class__))
            setattr(newevent,attr,value)
        newevent.__setattr__=newevent.__ro_setattr__
        return newevent

    def __hash__(self):
        return sum(hash(theval) for theval in self.__dict__.values())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self)==hash(other)

    def __ro_setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise AttributeError("'{0}' object attribute '{1}' is read-only".format(self.__class__.__name__,key))
```

It works remarkably well for something that's supposedly impossible; the only issue is that `newevent.__setattr__=newevent.__ro_setattr__` has no effect; it has the intended effect if I define it as `__setattr__` sans the "`ro_`", but that has the unpleasant side effect that I can't set attributes in `__new__()` either.

I know Python is between consenting adults, but on the other hand, mistakes happen - regularly. So I'd like to nip especially sneaky ones like accidentally changing a dict key's value in the bud before they waste days of my time. And yes, I could cave in and subclass `string`, but that would be *wroooong*~. I could also modify `__setattr__` to unroll the stack and fail to error if the caller is `InputEvent.__new__`, but that's butt-ugly, arguably *even worse* from a correctness standpoint, *and* at that point I'm beginning to worry about performance - this is for a video game, and input needs to happen *fast*!

So how can I close this one last loophole? How can I make my supposed immutable actually refuse attribute writes from everything but it's own class' `__new__()` without resorting to ugly stack hax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you should be able to use `__slots__` and the `@property` decorator should do a good job.

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
...         __slots__ = ['__thisattr', '__thatattr']
...         def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...             for name,val in kwargs.items():
...                setattr(self, "__"+name, val)
...         @property
...         def thisattr(self):
...             return self.__thisattr
...         @property
...         def thatattr(self):
...             return self.__thatattr

In [2]: f = Foo(thisattr="this", thatattr="that")

In [3]: f.thisattr
Out[3]: this

In [4]: f.thatattr
Out[4]: that

In [5]: f.thisattr = "Something Else"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-160d2a000ade> in <module>()
----> 1 f.thisattr = "something else"

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

You can certainly still do `f._Foo__thatattr = "Something else"`, but at that point you're breaking the safe word on purpose aren't you? It's not really "consenting adults" if you're going around trying to break things!

Comment: `__slots__` isn't an option, unless maybe I use metaclasses. The attributes of the event object have to be arbitrary. But that's a good thought! I could of course have one of the slots be a tuple of tuples of name,value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't satisfy the question, but here's the code I have in place for now for completeness' sake:

```
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name=="__new__":
            raise AttributeError("'{0}' object attribute '{1}' is read-only".format(self.__class__.__name__,key))
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self,key,value)
```

This simply looks to see if the function that called it was named `__new__`; this could well lead to complications in the future, but it does work. I'm not sure what the performance characteristics of doing the check every time an attribute is accessed are, though.